# Why don't sodium Voltage Gated Channels open during Repolarization?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, human-physiology

During Depolarization the Sodium VGC open when they receive the Threshold Stimulus. But when Repolarization occurs there comes a point when the cell interior has exactly the the same potential that it had during Depolarization *i.e.*,60mV but the Sodium VGC remain closed. Am I getting something wrong? If no, please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voltage-gated sodium channels have three basic states that represent different conformations of the protein: closed, open, and inactivated.

When a voltage-gated sodium channel is open at depolarized voltage, there is space for part of the channel to shift into a position that blocks the pore. When this happens, it gets stuck blocking the flow of sodium, and it requires a negative membrane potential to remove the block. We call this the "inactivated" state, and this model is called the [ball and chain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_and_chain_inactivation) of sodium channel inactivation.

The inactivation gating process is also referred to as the "h-gate", because h is the variable representing the gating in the classic [Hodgkin-Huxley model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model).

Wikipedia currently has a [useful table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_channel#Gating) on the sodium channel page showing the different states that a sodium channel goes through during different phases of an action potential.